# How to obtain smooth javascript popup resizing

Tags: javascript

I want a popup to resize to minimum size right before closing. I would like the user to see the animation so they understand the window they were using is disappearing.

I have come up with the following code, but it is very jaggy. Is there a smoother way?
Thank you!

```
function resizeWindow() {

    setTimeout(function() {
        window.resizeTo(500, 500);
    }, 100);
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.resizeTo(475, 475);
    }, 125);
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.resizeTo(450, 450);
    }, 150);
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.resizeTo(425, 425);
    }, 175);
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.resizeTo(400, 400);
    }, 200);
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.resizeTo(350, 350);
    }, 250)
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.resizeTo(300, 300);
    }, 300);
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.moveTo(900, 600);
    }, 350);
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.resizeTo(100, 100);
    }, 400);
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.resizeBy(10, 10);
    }, 500);
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.close();
    }, 500);

}
```

Comment: Do you want to resize an actual popup (new window) or a div inside your document that is styled as a popup?

Comment: it' s a new Windows (a separate popup, Mozilla style)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jQuery animation`
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

The below function can be used with any div size, and you can set any time you wish for the animation

```js
$(".closeBtn").click(function() {
  var parentElem = $(this).parents(".popup").first() ; //Get the parent div that needs to be closed
  
  parentElem.animate({ //set width and height of the parent div to 0
    "width": "0",
    "height": "0"
  },
  1000, //Animation time: 1000ms = 1 sec
  function() {
    parentElem.hide() ; //After the animation if finished, hide the div (you can use .remove() if you wish to remove the div completely
  })
}) ;
```

```css
.popup{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup">
  Pop up text goes here.
  <br />
  <a href="javascript:;" class="closeBtn">Click here to close</a>
</div>
```

> Updated Answer

Sorry for the above answer, but I miss understood the question.

I have came up with a solution. I don't know if it is the perfect solution. But at least it works.

The below is the popup window content.

I have created a function `animateClose()` that takes the `duration by milliseconds` as a parameter.

When called, it will calculate the window width and height, then will calculate the number of loops to do by dividing the duration given in the parameters by 10 (The popup will animate each 10 milliseconds)

When the popup reaches the given duration, it will be closed

```
<div class="main">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="closeWindow">Close Window</a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".closeWindow").click(function() {
            animateClose(500) ;
        }) ;
    }) ;

    function animateClose(time) {
        if (time == undefined || time == null) {
            time = 1000 ;
        }

        var w = $(window).width() ; //Get window width
        var h = $(window).height() ; //Get window height

        var loops = time * 0.1 ; //Get nb of loops

        var widthDecreasePercentage = (w / loops) * -1 ;
        var heightDecreasePercentage = (h / loops) * -1 ;

        var loopInterval = setInterval(function(){
            window.resizeBy(widthDecreasePercentage, heightDecreasePercentage) ;
            loops-- ;

            if (loops <= 0) {
                clearInterval(loopInterval) ;
                window.close() ;
            }
        }, 10);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer is about a div with class popup. OP is asking about an actual popup (new window)

Comment: Ohh. My bad. I didn't noticed that!

Comment: I checked it and it works very nicely (though for some reason the reducing does not take place at the same speed in width and heigth..)

Comment: How can I accept the answer (cannot see the check sign on the left!)?

Comment: Ok,  found it! I thought the JQuery one was a different answer... I'm accepting the "pure" JS one :-)
Thanks for the loop (calculating the original size to create a clear cut loop was a good idea:)

Comment: I just realized it was not a pure JS snipet!

Comment: Glad to be able to help you. The reducing have the same speed, but if the window width is higher than its height, then the width will resize faster so both of them will reach 0 width at the same time

Comment: I still accept the answer but would greatly appreaciate a pure JS solution. Any idea??

Comment: I understand: the ratio of reduction is not the same depending on original size...
Makes sense considering your code!

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`. I doubt that it solves the problem of "jaggy" animation but provides an improvement over code. [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/tonuluroze/edit?js,console,output)

```
var child = window.open("www.google.com","_blank","toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=0,left=0,width=500,height=500");
function resizeWindow(child) {
    var width = 500;
    var height = 500;
    var timer = setInterval(function(){ 
      if(width > 10) {
        child.resizeTo(width-=25,height-=25);
      }else{
        child.close();
        clearInterval(timer);
      }     
    },0);
}
resizeWindow(child);
```